# Can I download updates from another computer and then transfer it?

Tags: steam, technical-issues, pc, call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

Call of Duty Modern Warfare is very big game and it is getting new updates. The last one was 25 GB and in my home internet is very bad. I must take my PC to work then install update. Can I install last update to the my notebook instead of PC? I mean not whole game only the update.

Answer (score 2):

I actually came across the same problem and tried to do this. It will not work unless you have enough hard drive space on your notebook to download the ENTIRE game. You can not simply download sections in a safe, non shady way. (You probably can download a single update from a shady website where you will get a virus.)

If you do end up downloading the entire thing, you could probably transfer by either swapping hard drives (A lot of work) or transferring the files by connecting the notebook to your pc via usb. USB tends to be slow so it may not be faster than your home WiFi. The easiest way would probably be to buy a pcie hard drive and swap it back and forth. It would be hard to swap but the quickest way.

I actually thought about this solution but decided it wasn’t worth the effort even though I had a pcie hard drive.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this applies to your situation, but someone might find it useful.

One of my housemates keeps the game on an external disk with battlenet always open (to download any updates). After an update comes and is downloaded on that external, I connect it to my computer and use the opensource app [FreeFileSync](https://freefilesync.org/) to copy over only the files that changed.

Sometimes it saves quite a few GB, and for me only takes 5-10 minutes typically. Haven't done a speed test yet to see if copying over the entire folder natively is faster than FreeFileSync's copy, I'll report back here when I do.

### Tips for FreeFileSync

- Make sure you don't get the source and target mixed up!

  - Left pane is the new version to copy, right pane is your local older version.
- Use the "File content" comparison option.
- Use the "Mirror" synchronization option.